# ether.js accessing public views

Tags: javascript, solidity, ethers.js, ether

I have 2 public views in my smart contract but when I try to access them with ether.js if I try with callStatic like that:

```
NVAContract.callStatic.calculateTotal(address)
```

it throws an error: callStatic undefined

If I try like that:

```
NVAContract.calculateTotal(address)
```

it asks for gas fees. (the contract and the abi are right, double checked the abi and the same contract object works when using write functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I just realized I was using ethers.js 3, switching to version 4 fixed the problem.